# React navigation how can I reach nested route navigators?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to reach navigation or route prop of components from parent navigation. For example this example is from [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In Stack screen with name Home there is a component named Home and this home is a tab nav. I want to reach navigation or route prop of this tab components. What I want to do is, in a component which isnt part of Tab navigator, detecting current selected tab. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `useRoute()` hook. From [RN docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route):

> `useRoute` is a hook which gives access to `route` object. It's useful when you cannot pass the `route` prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.
> `useRoute()` returns the route prop of the screen it's inside.

Example from docs:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyText() {
  const route = useRoute();

  return <Text>{route.params.caption}</Text>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I wanted to share a working example, as the answer provided will not give a parent component access the a nested route using `useRoute()`. I believe that is what the OP asked.

In your file where you initiate `<NavigationContainer />`, first, import and create a ref using the method provided by ReactNavigation introduced v6:

```js
import { NavigationContainer, createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native'

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()
```

and then add the ref to your `<NavigationContainer />`:

```js
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}><App /></NavigationContainer>
```

This will allow you to get the details of the current route, from a parent:

```js
console.log(navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute())
```

Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization