# How can get route name of a double nested screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

[image]

In StackScreenΑ if get route name I will take StackScreenΒ1 or StackScreenΒ2 depending on which page I'm on.

The same in StackScreenB1 if get route name I will take ScreenC1 or ScreenC2 or ScreenC3 depending on which page I'm on.

Is there any way when I am on StackScreenΑ to get route name on Nested Screens of StackScreenB1.

Explain. I am on stage A and I want to get the route name of stage C and not B.

*For get route name of B when I am on A , alert(route.name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to make it work using the following code.

AppContext.js

```
export default AppContext = { navigationRef: null };
```

App.js

```
...
<NavigationContainer ref={ref => AppContext.navigationRef = ref}>
...
```

YourFile.js

```
console.log(AppContext.navigationRef?.getCurrentRoute().name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had struggle with the nav as well. I made this post, and finally understood how to nest different navigations:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72834227/8119333
In this, I made a stack nav into a bottom tab nav. I think you can do exactly de same with 2 stack nav and navigate from anywhere to anywhere.

so when you declare your route a the very top of you app:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>              
          <Stack.Screen name='screenA' component={ComponentA} />
          <Stack.Screen name='screenB' component={ComponentB} />
          <Stack.Screen name='screenC' component={ComponentC} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Your route names are `screenA` , `screenB` and `screenC`

Comment: I don't want to navigate, I want only to get route name nothing more. I know all the functions for react native navigation but I want something different, out of the box.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by "the route name".
You mean the route in the props ? console.log(JSON.stringify(route, null,4)) to check the object of your route ?

Comment: route name is the name of the current page of navigation. for example: If I am in A1 and get route name I will take rout.name=B1 or B2 it depends on which page I am on. If I am in B1 and get route name I will take rout.name=C1 or C2 or C3 it depends on which page I am on. Route name is a variable of navigation.

Comment: const YourComponent= ({ route }) => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(route, null, 4))
const yourRoute = route.name ...

Comment: I haven't understood your reasoning, this code does the same thing as writing a simple get route.name. I know how to get route name for the current screen but I want to be in Stack A and be able to get the route.name of Screen C,

Comment: edited, but I guess I still not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer works, React Navigation v6 + introduces a method that does the same through a provided method. I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76692050/731782

In your file where you initiate `<NavigationContainer />`, first, import and create a ref using the method provided by ReactNavigation:

```js
export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()
```

and then add the ref:

```js
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}><App /></NavigationContainer>
```

Then use the ref in a component where needed:

```js
console.log(navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute())
```

Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization